# Dynamic Source prosjection when using Data flow on Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have an data flow that compares two similar files ( the original and the new one), the new rows from the new file are added (appended) on the original one.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcm8g.png)

I works fine.
My issue is that this work flow will be reused by 10 different files using parameters that are in a json file.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zN3kA.png)

I works almost fine.

My big issue is that metadata differs from each file and data factory doesnt adapp accordingly.

As an example. file1 :
file projection is perfect.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJNZJ.png)

althought data factory when iterates to the second still have the same projection even though metadata differs. the result is : empty columns ....
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gqUqX.png)

I need to data factory to dynamically find out metadata from each table and addapt accordingly.

How can I do that ? there is no option under "optimize" to set some dynamic parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your scenario in my environment as you are appending new values to old file from multiple new files so schema for all files should be same. because you are passing files dynamically if these is different schema for a single file the data flow will not detect it and throw error.

**Keep projection imported for dynamic files so if new file with similar schema comes it will detect it:**
[image]
**Pipeline running successfully:**
[image]

> **Output without null values:**

**Initial sample new file**
[image]
**Initial sample old file**
[image]
**Appended sample old file**
[image]